# MVC3 Editing model ignores setter logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, validation

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and the Entity Framework to build a little application.

I've got a model representing a social event, which has a "maximum number of attendees" and "currently registered attendees". When editing the event, the user can change the event's capacity, but I want to prevent them from changing the capacity to a value lower than the amount of people currently registered.

I naively assumed I could just add this logic to my setter for the Capacity property in my Event model, but it seems this logic is ignored and the value is updated anyways...

Here's the complete updated model:

```
public class SocialEvent : IValidatableObject
{
    public SocialEvent()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<Person>();
    }


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int Capacity { get; set; }

    public int SlotsRemaining { get { return Capacity - Attending; } }
    public int Attending { get { return Users.Count; } }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Users { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Capacity < Attending)
        {
            var campo = new[] { "Capacity" };
            yield return new ValidationResult("Capacity cannot be less than number of confirmed attendees.", campo);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code from my controller, this is mostly auto-generated stuff and I'm guessing this is where the issue is:

```
    //
    // GET: /Event/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        SocialEvent socialevent = db.SocialEvents.Find(id);
        return View(socialevent);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Event/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(SocialEvent socialevent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(socialevent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(socialevent);
    }
```

Here's my view containing the fields used to edit the model:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>NadEvent</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Capacity)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Capacity)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Capacity)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

What's the best solution here, how can I add my own logic when setting the capacity to prevent the user from selecting an invalid number? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot make this assumptions when you use the `ModelState` the rules are related specific to the `DataAnnotations` defined in your model, in your case for the type of your validation you need to implement the interface `IValidatableObject` and override the method `Validate` so can defined you custom server side validations that needs to be executed

For example

```
public class SocialEvent : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(Capacity < Attending)
        {
           var campo = new[] { "Capacity" }; 
           yield return new ValidationResult("Capacity cannot be less than number of confirmed attendees.", campo);  
        }
    }

}
```

When you work in mvc you could defined some `"automatic"` validations with this Annotations for example

```
[Required] <--- this forces in the view to be a required field
public string email {get ; set;}
```

[In this link you cand find all the DataAnnotations that you can use in your models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)
[Also in this link](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/dataannotations-and-aspnet-mvc.html) you could see some examples of this data annotations

Last Update

By default you're not filling the `Attending` field values because the ICollection of users it's empty, second even if this works and the beginning you should consider add the field as a hide value, when you click in the windows you should serialized that field you can have the value

Modified your Edit View adding the Attending Field

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Attending)
```

Fill the `ICollection<Uers>` because there's no way that you can get the value in the attending value check the query generated by linq and your database and see if are well related.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful... I have some other properties that I didn't include in the original post to save space, including like a Date field. Am I going to have to manually validate all those fields now if I am overriding the Validate function?

Comment: give me two minutes to explain a little be more about the DataAnnotations

Comment: Thank you. I'm finding now that "Attending" is showing up as 0, even though it's definitely not 0. Any idea why this would be? It displays the correct value for "Attending" in the view, but when I get into the "Validate" method, it's value is 0. Sorry if this isn't enough information.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the fact that the "Attending" property is just returning the "Count" property on the "Users" list, and it's showing the users list as empty for some reason, but only in this context. Everywhere else in the application it retrieves the number correctly. Does my "User" class need to implement some sort of interface to interact correctly with this Validate method?

Comment: Did you modified the Model? if you did it update your question with the new model

Comment: I updated the model in the original question. I'm suspecting that because there is that "Users" list that references another table, it's for some reason empty in this particular context and not retrieving the actual data from the database?

Comment: I "solved" this by adding a reference to my database as a private data member in my SocialEvent class, and then changing "Attending" to be db.SocialEvents.Find(this.Id).Users.Count... It works, but this can't be right, haha...